# Symfony 1.4 and MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server-2008, symfony1, database-connection, symfony-1.4, propel

I figured out how to use the php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll drive for PHP and want Symfony to connect to a MS SQL 2008 database.
Looks like Doctrine doesn't allow MS SQL data engine and I have to use sfPropel15Plugin-1.1.5 plugin.

I just start with Symfony and don't understand the install instructions and how to use the database, can someone help me, from a project clean setup what to do to connect to that MS SQL database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToConnectToMSSQLServer